# Feedburner - Multiple feeds in multiple languages

Tags: rss, feeds

I run a website that available in Dutch and English. Each 'language version' has its own blog and related [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) feed. I want to publish these RSS feeds through [Feedburner](http://www.feedburner.com). Obviously I would like to have the Feedburner UI for the Dutch readers in Dutch and the English speaker readers in English.

Does anybody know how to manage multiple feeds with multiple languages in Feedburner.

Answer (score 2):

You will likely need to setup separate Feedburner feeds for each language since the source RSS will be coming from two different places.  Within the feed settings on Feedburner, if you go to the 'Optimize' tab, the 'BrowserFriendly' section allows you to change the language of the theme that is used by Feedburner so that your subscribers have a language specific interface (the ClearFeed theme has both an English and Dutch version).

From the 'Publicize' tab, the 'Email Subscriptions' setting has a similar setting, although the number of languages there is fairly limited (it does not look like Dutch is an option).